# How to use nginx rewrite?

Tags: nginx, rewrite

So I've been playing with rewrite for awhile, and I can't get it.

Basically, when a user visits `http://mydomain.com/images/username.png` I want it to actually display the results of `http://mydomain.com/stats.php?user=username`

This was what I had before I finally gave up:

`rewrite  "/images/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).png" /home/wwwroot/stats.php?user=$1;`

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the file path for your replacement.  Try this:

```
rewrite ^/images/([-\w]+)\.png$ /stats.php?user=$1;
```

And you'll want to make sure that your PHP code is setting the right MIME type on the response.